# Baseline issue in ListView

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I am comparing a ListView containing TextView items under Android Gingerbread (2.3.1) and ICS (4.0.3).

Using the Hierarchy View, I see that, for the same contents, the *getBaseline()* property is different in these 2 versions of Android.

Under **Gingerbread**, property *getBaseline()* is **23** for all items.
Under **ICS**, property *getBaseline()* is **58** for some items, **23** otherwise.
And the items with baseline 58 are invisible (the text content is there, just out of sight).

Do you know of anything that could have had modified the baseline ?
 I believe I'll need to fix this to make the text visible.
My code does some styling of the items, based on content, but I do not consciously manipulate the baseline.

Comment: This behavious is related to using two different text sizes in **getView()**. It happens when I toggle between two fixed values with **setTextSize()**. If I stick to one size it's fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by changing the xml item template.
I did some testing with a simpler layout (the RelativeLayout in http://www.curious-creature.org/2009/02/22/android-layout-tricks-1 ). It worked.

When I reverted back to the original (non functional) xml it also worked... Strange.
Anyway, the lesson is: don't forget to check the xml.